# copy and paste to the next cell using a loop with the datas in different columns

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Hi I'm fairly new to VBA and I want to loop this code. as of right now this code is copying data in Range ("B30:B") from the "Ba Pricing" to the destination worksheet and it will copy the same data to the last cell. What I wanted this to do is loop this code where it will copy the data in columns (E, H, K and N) and paste it to last cell of the "Loader" worksheet. with the condition if there is no data in each column then don't copy.

Thanks

```
Sub Copy_Paste_Below_Last_Cell()
'Find the last used row in both sheets and copy and paste data below existing data.

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

  'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
  Set wsCopy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ba pricing")
  Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Loader")

  '1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column A
  lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

  '2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column A
  'Offset property moves down 1 row
  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

  '3. Copy & Paste Data
  wsCopy.Range("B30:B" & lCopyLastRow).Copy
    wsDest.Range("C" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


End Sub
```

It should look something like this...

```
PriceDate
4/23/2019
4/24/2019
4/25/2019
4/26/2019
4/27/2019
4/28/2019
4/29/2019
4/30/2019
5/1/2019
5/2/2019
5/3/2019
5/4/2019
5/5/2019
5/6/2019
5/7/2019
5/8/2019
5/9/2019
5/10/2019
5/11/2019
5/12/2019
5/13/2019
5/14/2019
5/15/2019
5/16/2019
4/23/2019
4/24/2019
4/25/2019
4/26/2019
4/27/2019
4/28/2019
4/29/2019
4/30/2019
5/1/2019
5/2/2019
5/3/2019
5/4/2019
5/5/2019
5/6/2019
4/23/2019
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how to loop through columns

```
Dim CopyColumns() As Variant
CopyColumns = Array("B", "E", "H", "K", "N")

Dim Col As Variant
For Each Col In CopyColumns

    lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row

    wsCopy.Range(Col & "30:" & Col & lCopyLastRow).Copy
    wsDest.Range("C" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Next Col
```

Comment: Sorry I should've been clearer. what I'm trying to do is copy the dates from each columns in array B30:B, E30:E, H30:H, K30:K, N30:N  in "wsCopy" and paste it all in column C the "wsDest". is that possible? @Pᴇʜ

Comment: @thanh1211 See my edit. Note that `Col` contains the column name like `"B"` …

Comment: thank you! it work! I have one more question.... is there a way to do the same exact thing where it populate column C but this time populate column H with a different data along with it?

Comment: The range in column H (same rows as populated in column C) would be `wsDest.Range("H" & lDestLastRow, "H" & lDestLastRow + lCopyLastRow - 29)` just populate your data there